# Accessing specific characters of dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I have a dictionary such as:

```py
{
    apples.1: aaaaaaappplllllleeeeeeeeees,
    bananas.1: baaaanaaaaanaaaaaaaaaaasssssssss,
    strawberries.1: straaaawwwwwbeeeeerriiiiies
}
```

I want to access the `1st`, `10th`, and `15th` character of each value in my dictionary:

The output I am looking for is something like:

```
apples.1: a, p, l
bananas.1: b, a, a
strawberries.1: s, w, e
```

I know that for strings we can use something like:

```py
a, b, c = some_str[0], some_str[9], some_str[14]
```

But I am out of my depth when it comes to dictionaries.

Comment: Your missing quotes around your keys and values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you execute `dict[x]` you are accessing the value where the key is x in your dictionary.
In your case the value is a String so you can manipulate this string with e.g:

```
dict[x][:2]
```

This snipped will return the first two characters. If you want to select the nth character use:

```
dict[x][n]
```

In your specific example use:

```
dict['apples.1'][2]
```

to get the third charater of the string

Answer (score 1):

You can enumerate the keys and values of a dictionary thus:

```
d = {
    'apples.1': 'aaaaaaappplllllleeeeeeeeees',
    'bananas.1': 'baaaanaaaaanaaaaaaaaaaasssssssss',
    'strawberries.1': 'straaaawwwwwbeeeeerriiiiies'
}

for key, value in d.items():
    a, b, c = value[0], value[9], value[14]
    print(f'{key}: {a}, {b}, {c}')
```

Prints:

```
apples.1: a, p, l
bananas.1: b, a, a
strawberries.1: s, w, e
```

Comment: thank you! what happens if my dictionary, instead of 3 key-values, has > 100?

Comment: 100 keys or for each key 100 values? I am not really following.

Comment: An item is just a key/value pair. You print 100 lines. So what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the corresponding value for each key, and then proceed to retrieve the 1st, 10th and 15th value.

like this:

```
dict = {
    "apples.1": "aaaaaaappplllllleeeeeeeeees",
    "bananas.1": "baaaanaaaaanaaaaaaaaaaasssssssss",
    "strawberries.1": "straaaawwwwwbeeeeerriiiiies"
}

for val in dict.values():
    first, tenth, fifteenth = val[0], val[9], val[14]
    print(first, tenth, fifteenth)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dic= {
apples: 'aaaaaaappplllllleeeeeeeeees',
bananas: 'baaaanaaaaanaaaaaaaaaaasssssssss',
strawberries: 'straaaawwwwwbeeeeerriiiiies'
}

```
Dic[apples]=Dic[apples][5]
Dic[bananas]=Dic[bananas][5]
Dic[bananas]=Dic[bananas][0:5]

print(Dic)
```

Output:

```
{
        apples: 'a',
        bananas: 'a',
        strawberries: 'straa'
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: if you are happy with the answer , I will be grateful if you vote .

Answer (score 0):

```
dict = {"apples" : "aaaaaaappplllllleeeeeeeeees", "bananas" : "baaaanaaaaanaaaaaaaaaaasssssssss", "strawberries" : "straaaawwwwwbeeeeerriiiiies"}

x = list(d.values())  # I transformed dict values into list to be able to slice them
print(x[0][0], x[0][10], x[0][15])
print(x[1][0], x[1][10], x[1][15])
print(x[2][0], x[2][10], x[2][15])
```

output

```
a l l
b a a
s w e
```

enjoy :-)